# SSL handshake failure w/ self-signed certificates

Tags: node.js, curl, https, ssl-certificate, handshake

When I run `curl -k https://localhost:8080/` from the terminal, I get the following error:

`curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Code: (language is coffeescript)

```
https = require 'https'

fs = require 'fs'

options = 
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key')
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
  requestCert: false
  rejectUnauthorized: false

server = https.createServer(options, 
  (req, res) =>
    console.log "TEST"
)

server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP)
```

Other info:
I'm running these on Cloud9's UNIX machines.
The certificates are free, self-signed things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html,

"During the generation of the CSR, you will be prompted for several pieces of information. These are the X.509 attributes of the certificate. One of the prompts will be for "Common Name (e.g., YOUR name)". **It is important that this field be filled in with the fully qualified domain name of the server to be protected by SSL.** If the website to be protected will be https://public.akadia.com, then enter public.akadia.com at this prompt."

A mismatch between the "Common Name" in the certificate and the URL that you are `curl`ing will cause exactly the issue that you're encountering! Try regenerating your certificate with "Common Name" as your *fully specified* URL.